# Resize cell columns when copying multiple selection of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting error 1004 "copy area is not same size/shape" on this code:

I've tried inserting various .pastespecials, .selection.autofit in places....but I'm kinda stabbing around in the dark.

Help?

```
Sub SaveData()

Dim rr As Range
Set rr = Selection

For Each Row In rr

   'error occurs here'
    Range("a" & i & ":BN" & i).Copy Worksheets("ArchiveData").Cells(Worksheets("ArchiveData").Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
    Sheets("ArchiveData").Cells(Worksheets("archivedata").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 1).Value = Date



    Next Row
```

End Sub

Comment: Replace `i` with `rr` and I suspect that will fix your issue. You don't have i as a variable anywhere in the code you've posted, so if it's relevant, you'll have to explain more.

Comment: Right. Replaced `i` with `rr` but still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use OPTION EXPLICIT!!! *(Tools > Options > Editor > Require Variable Declaration)*

Now to this particular problem (which would have been clear with Option Explicit on.

`Row`  in `For Each Row In rr` is seen as a variable or object, not as a Row of the range rr.

what you need to use is

```
Dim rr As Range
Dim rrrow as Range

Set rr = Selection

For Each rrrow In rr.Rows
```

Now next is the problem that `i` is not dimensioned either, and doesnt even have a value, thus it will most probably be zero or empty (0 or "" or NULL)

I guess you want want to proceed something like:

```
rrrow.Copy
With Worksheets("ArchiveData")
    .Range(........).PasteSpecial 'HERE YOU ONLY NEED TO SPECIFY THE TOP LEFT MOST CELL
End With
```

Comment: Hmm followed your lead but now it's throwing a compile error: "sub/function not defined" at the `with worksheet("archivedata')` line. My range is on "Master" sheet. When it copies to "archivedata" it needs to copy to the next empty row.

Comment: my bad, you need to use `Worksheets("ArchiveData")` I changed it accordingly

Comment: gah, I should've seen that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
Sub SaveData()

    Dim rr As Range
    Set rr = Selection


    Dim wsht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsht = Worksheets("ArchiveData")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wsht Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For i = 1 To rr.Rows.Count

        Range("a" & i & ":BN" & i).Copy wsht.Cells(wsht.Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
        wsht.Cells(wsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 1).Value = Date

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The `For i =1` statement is only copying row 1 of my sheet. I can alter it to select more than one cell as long as it's a continuous range. My original code is "supposedly" able to let me select multiple cells that aren't necessarily (guest name in "A2" and guest name in "A4" but it won't let me paste because of the column width.